# Getting different marker colors based on conditions gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I have a case where I want to show the marker in green color if someone is not registered and red color if someone is registered in a city. I have gone through the doc but could not find anything related to it.

How do I go about changing the colors of markers as per my conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem doesn't include marker color styling. I see only one solution:

- create marker picture for each kind of marker
- include your logic in `gmaps4rails_marker_picture` to render the appropriate one